# Eventbrite API and Pagination

Tags: api, pagination, eventbrite

When querying the Eventbrite API the results are paginated, however, the API documentation doesn't describe how to request page 2 and beyond.

I have tried adding various parameters to the request including "page", "paging", and "pagination" but none of them work and page 1 is always returned.

Can anyone tell me how to do this properly?

Cheers,
-Josh.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the PHP class I was using was mangling the parameters.

The correct parameter to use for pagination is "page".

Comment: Please share URL for pagination.Event Get API.

Answer (score 0):

```
events/{{event_id}}/attendees/?token={{token}}&page=2
```